# Deserialize JSON subdocument

Tags: c#, json, api, rest, serialization

I'm calling the JIRA Rest API to recieve a list of Worklog Objects.

The JSON I recieve looks like.

```
{
"startAt": 0,
"maxResults": 1,
"total": 1,
"worklogs": [
    {
        "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/10010/worklog/10000",
        "author": {
            "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=fred",
            "name": "fred",
            "displayName": "Fred F. User",
            "active": false
        },
        "updateAuthor": {
            "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=fred",
            "name": "fred",
            "displayName": "Fred F. User",
            "active": false
        },
        "comment": "I did some work here.",
        "visibility": {
            "type": "group",
            "value": "jira-developers"
        },
        "started": "2015-08-25T07:43:10.086+0000",
        "timeSpent": "3h 20m",
        "timeSpentSeconds": 12000,
        "id": "100028"
    }
]
}
```

As I said, I want to put it in a list.

```
var json = client.MakeRequest("", password, user);
List<Worklog> myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Worklog>>(json);
```

It doesn't work, because of

```
"startAt": 0,
"maxResults": 1,
"total": 1,
```

How can I make the deserializer ignore those properties?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create a "RootObject" class that does contain the properties:

```
public class RootObject 
{
    public int startAt { get; set; }
    public int maxResults { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<Worklog> worklogs { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize into that:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
// access rootObject.worklogs
```

Or step into the parsed JSON and deserialize from there:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken worklogsJson = o.SelectToken("worklogs");
var worklogs = worklogsJson.ToObject<List<Worklog>>();
```

Comment: Both ways lead to a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException (Additional information: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'worklogs[0].author')

Comment: Does not happen for me. Update your question with the actual JSON and classes you use.

Comment: Used a selfwritten Worklog class instead of the one in the (horrible) Atlassian SDK, now it works. Thank you!